# Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:compileDebugRenderscript' (type 'RenderscriptCompile')

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:compileDebugRenderscript' (type 'RenderscriptCompile').

  - In plugin 'com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidBasePlugin' type 'com.android.build.gradle.tasks.RenderscriptCompile' method 'useAndroidX()' should not be annotated with: @Input.

    Reason: Input/Output annotations are ignored if they are placed on something else than a getter.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Remove the annotations.
    2. Rename the method.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.6.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_method for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidBasePlugin' type 'com.android.build.gradle.tasks.RenderscriptCompile' property 'ndkConfig' is missing an input or output annotation.

    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Add an input or output annotation.
    2. Mark it as @Internal.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.6.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.

I ran flutter build apk in terminal  apart from that Havent tried anything yet as i am a beginner and was cloning a project from github on vscode its  a flutter ecommerce app. Please help me fix this and give me step by step guidance for  a beginner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to do a few things to fix this.

1. Updated compileSdkVersion to 33
2. Check Java version (`java --version`) and the find the compatible gradle version from https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html
3. Update that version in `gradle-wrapper.properties`
4. In build.gradle add in dependencies add the tool version

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0' for 7.6 version

5. I then got Kotlin Gradle Plugin error, so had to find the KGP version for Gradle from https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle-configure-project.html
6. In `build.gradle` update the `ext.kotlin_version = <compatible version>`

After a lot pain finally build succeeded

Comment: Thanks for this really appreciate your input.