# getting error when running flutter app Reason: Input/Output annotations are ignored if they are placed on something else than a getter

Tags: flutter

The plugin `flutter_bluetooth_basic` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Upgrading build.gradle
Conflict detected between Android Studio Java version and Gradle version, upgrading Gradle version from 5.6.2 to 7.6.1.
Upgrading gradle-wrapper.properties
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:compileDebugRenderscript' (type 'RenderscriptCompile').

  - In plugin 'com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidBasePlugin' type 'com.android.build.gradle.tasks.RenderscriptCompile' method 'useAndroidX()' should not be annotated with: @Input.

    Reason: Input/Output annotations are ignored if they are placed on something else than a getter.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Remove the annotations.
    2. Rename the method.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.6.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_method for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidBasePlugin' type 'com.android.build.gradle.tasks.RenderscriptCompile' property 'ndkConfig' is missing an input or output annotation.

    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Add an input or output annotation.
    2. Mark it as @Internal.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.6.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 10s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Have you tried this solution -> [https://stackoverflow.com/a/76669345/14384776](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76669345/14384776)